# How can I reach a shortcut folder on IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7, virtual-directory

I have a shortcut folder on iis under wwwroot file. But I do not reach it like this : 
**www.mydomain/myshortcutfolder/a.jpg**
How can I reach it?

I do not want to create virtual directory because my orginal file has write permission but I want to create shortcut folder , I want it has just read permission,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a Junction.  It's powerful, cool, but scary, too.  Read carefully.

It works only for folders on the same physical NTFS drive.  If you delete a file from a junction folder, you delete the source, too.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

BTW, permissions on a virtual directory in IIS can be different that the folder permissions.  Set IIS so the folder is read only.

Chas Callaway

Answer (score 0):

You can reset IIS using Start -> Run -> cmd -> iisreset

You can go to IIS Manager using : **Start -> Run -> inetmgr**